# mongodb update field async driver

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, driver

How to update a field in a collection using mongodb allanbank async driver?

When I say

```
db.getCollection("coll_name").update( //$NON-NLS-1$
                 BuilderFactory.start().add("_id", docObjectId),
                 BuilderFactory.start().add("field", value)); //$NON-NLS-1$
```

I get the necessary field updated to the new value, but all the other fields in the document disappear. In other words, what's the analogue of `$set` in mongo shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I greatly appreciate Rob Moore's answer, his help was really invaluable. But there's a slight inaccuracy: I had to add `pop()` so that everything worked. So:

```
DocumentBuilder update = BuilderFactory.start();
update = (DocumentBuilder)update.push("$set").add("field", value).pop(); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$

db.getCollection("coll").update( //$NON-NLS-1$
    BuilderFactory.start().add("_id", docObjectId), //$NON-NLS-1$
    update);
```

Comment: What version of the driver are you using?  If my current version didn't work that is a bug.  I had a forgotten the pop in the first version of the answer which I edited to not need by pulling the update construction outside of the update invocation.  In you version (which works too) you should not need the pop() and assignment back to 'update'.  The DocumentBuilder tracks its sub-builders and resolves them to final form at build time.

Comment: @RobMoore I need also the pop() to work correctly using last 2.0.1 driverversion. If not the $set operator is lost

Comment: @lujop Would you mind writing up a issue with a simple test case? https://github.com/allanbank/mongodb-async-driver/issues Thanks Rob.

Comment: @RobMoore It was my fault, I was confused with the builder. If your exactly code is used, and you save a reference at the place when you create the builder it works correctly. The problem was that I used a reference got at the final stage of building.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the $set operator directly with a sub-document.  e.g.,

```
DocumentBuilder update = BuilderFactory.start();
update.push("$set").add("field", value); //$NON-NLS-1$

db.getCollection("coll_name").update( //$NON-NLS-1$
             BuilderFactory.start().add("_id", docObjectId),
             update);
```